# useState-hook is not updating my state in an onPress() function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building a tab-view and I cannot figure out why the useState-hook is not updating my state. I am sure it is something easy, but I have been stumped here a while now...

I can see that the onPress function is fired and that item.label is the correct one if I log that out. However, setState does not change, even if I hardcode the parameter.

```
const TabContainer = ({ tabs }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');

function renderItem(item, index) {
    return item.label === selected ? (
      <View style={styles.selectedTab}>
        <CustomText style={styles.tabText}>{item.label}</CustomText>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={index}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(selected);
          setSelected(item.label);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.tab}>
          <CustomText style={styles.tabText}>{item.label}</CustomText>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        data={tabs}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return renderItem(item, index);
        }}
        style={styles.listContainer}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default TabContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I kinda solved this. I realized that I had to lift my state up for my tabs in order to render the other stuff properly. So then I just implemented in the same way in the parent component, and then it worked...

Important rows from parent:

```
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('');

  function handleTabPress(tab) {
    setSelectedTab(tab);
  }

...

<TabContainer
  tabs={[
    { label: 'Label 1' },
    { label: 'Label 2' },
    { label: 'Label 3' },
  ]}
  selectedTab={selectedTab}
  handleTabPress={handleTabPress}
/>
```

New child

```
const TabContainer = ({ tabs, selectedTab, handleTabPress }) => {
  function renderItem(item, index) {
    return item.label === selectedTab ? (
      <View style={styles.selectedTab}>
        <CustomText style={styles.selectedTabText}>{item.label}</CustomText>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={index}
        onPress={() => {
          handleTabPress(item.label);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.tab}>
          <CustomText style={styles.tabText}>{item.label}</CustomText>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        data={tabs}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return renderItem(item, index);
        }}
        style={styles.listContainer}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<

TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={index}
        onPress={() => onPressItem(item)}
      >
const onPressItem =(item)=>{
setSelected(item.label)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, using useRef instead of useState when you want to set a value at a different stage in the lifecycle than the constructor.
Please take a look at this and try to implement this in your code:
[https://codesandbox.io/s/v6948pww5y?from-embed]

Comment: Hm okey I will try this. But why? Isn't this exactly how useState should work? I want it to rerender when the tab is selected etc

Comment: "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?" 

It is not possible for this component... I'd rather not feed it down to the child component, that is code smell imo